# Composition over Inheritance and Tight Coupling

Tags: java, oop

I am a complete beginner so forgive my ignorance. 
I have created a project where I have used composition in some classes. 
In my Cinema class I have a Schedule object.

```
public class Cinema {        

private String name;        //set via constructor
private int seatCount;  // set in constructor  
private int rowCount;   // set in constructor  
private int cleanUpTime;        //set via constructor 
private LocalTime openTime = LocalTime.of(9, 30);        
private LocalTime closeTime = LocalTime.of(23, 59);      
private LocalTime peakTime = LocalTime.of(16, 30);   
private int costPerHour;        //set via constructor
private Schedule schedule = new Schedule(this);

//Constructors, other methods....
}
```

A Schedule belongs to a Cinema. It needs a Cinema object for some of its methods. A Schedule can not exist without a Cinema.

When reading about OOP I am led to believe that I have created a class that is now tightly coupled to another class and that is potentially bad.

Therefore how could I improve this design?

I have a few tightly coupled classes it seems.  e.g Booking class and Customer class. A booking has a Customer and a Customer contains a list of all Bookings they have made.

I thought I was using composition and that would be good but now I am confused as I have read about coupling.

Please help me understand.

Comment: I think that composition vs inheritance and tight coupling are all matters of opinion which it's not worth concerning yourself about. Better to ask yourself : Is the code robust and maintainable?

Comment: Interesting. It is fairly robust and easy to maintain as it is a really small application. But this is for an assignment about good understanding off oop and I fear that my tightly coupled classes will lose me valuable marks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has to be some coupling.  A Cinema and a Schedule are not completely independent.

> A Schedule belongs to a Cinema.

So far, so good.

> It needs a Cinema object for some of its methods.

Nope.  A Schedule object should be able to stand on it's own.

Since you haven't provided any code, I'll make the following assumptions.

- A cinema shows one or more movies.
- A movie has a schedule for each day of the week, for as long as the movie is shown.

So here's a Schedule class.

```
public class Schedule {
    private final Calendar showingTimestamp;

    public Schedule(Calendar showingTimestamp) {
        this.showingTimestamp = showingTimestamp;
    }

    public Calendar getShowingTimestamp() {
        return showingTimestamp;
    }

    public int getShowingWeekday() {
        return showingTimestamp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    }

}
```

The only field on the Schedule class holds a showing date and a showing time.  I showed you how to use a Calendar method to get the weekday.

Here's a bare bones Movie class.

```
public class Movie {
    private final String name;

    private List<Schedule> showingList;

    public Movie(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.showingList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addShowing(Schedule schedule) {
        this.showingList.add(schedule);
    }

    public List<Schedule> getShowingList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(showingList);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The Movie class knows about the Schedule class.  The Schedule class does not know about the Movie class.

Finally, here's the Cinema class.

```
public class Cinema {

    private final String name;

    private List<Movie> currentMovieList;

    public Cinema(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.currentMovieList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addCurrentMovie0(Movie movie) {
        this.currentMovieList.add(movie);
    }

    public void removeMovie(Movie oldMovie) {
        for (int index = currentMovieList.size() - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
            Movie movie = currentMovieList.get(index);
            if (movie.getName().equals(oldMovie.getName())) {
                currentMovieList.remove(index);
            }
        }
    }

    public List<Movie> getCurrrentMovieList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(currentMovieList);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

The Cinema class knows about the Movie class, and indirectly, about the Schedule class.  The Movie class does not know about the Cinema class.

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: Thanks for responding. For some additional background, My Schedule class creates Shows (Shows is another class). It adds these Shows to an arraylist it has as a member. This list is the shows for the week (similar to your currentMovieList);  but it is the Schedule that holds this list and not the Cinema.   Schedule's method gets information from its Cinema object.  So for example, clean up time, closing time, cinema size.  This allows showings to schedule correctly for a cinema (eg large cinema takes longer to clean).

Comment: @Urban Gemz: And you're over coupling the model.  Creating the model as I described minimizes the coupling.

Answer (score 2):

It is fine to have a Cinema object and list of Schedule objects inside it. One to Many relationship I suppose.

Comment: It is more of a one to one relationship. One Cinema has one Schedule and a Schedule has only one Cinema.

Answer (score 1):

Where suitable, using composition instead of inheritance is indeed a good design practice.  Your question is not really about that, though: I don't see a plausible inheritance-based alternative to the composition you have formed.

Suppose that you were trying to design classes for a system that can distinguish IMAX cinemas from other cinemas, with a consistent interface but different behavior.  You might consider creating `ImaxCinema` as a subclass of `Cinema` and overriding methods as needed to customize its behavior:

```
class ImaxCinema extends Cinema {
    @Override
    int getScreenWidth() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That's the the "inheritance" alternative.

On the other hand, you might create an interface `ProjectorType`, with implementations `Standard` and `Imax` that implement the varying behavior.  If you give the `Cinema` class a member of type `ProjectorType` then you can provide for the varying behavior by the class of the object assigned to that member:

```
class Cinema {
    ProjectorType projector;

    int getScreenWidth() {
        return projector.getScreenWidth();
    }
}
```

That's a common form of the "composition" alternative.

Your situation does not bear on inheritance vs. composition because no customization of behavior is involved.

---

Avoiding tight coupling between classes is a separate consideration, and *also* a good design principle.  Your `Cinema` and `Schedule` classes are indeed tightly coupled, as is evident already in the fact the `Schedule`'s constructor requires a `Cinema` argument.

Consider, however, the iterators of Collections classes.  Each one is inherently specific to a particular collection class, as it must navigate the idiosynchratic internal data structures of that class to do its job properly.  Each iterator's class is therefore tightly coupled to the associated collection class, and that's OK.  That avoiding tight coupling is *generally* a good principle does not mean that the quality of every single design is anticorrelated with the degree of coupling.

In your particular case, I don't quite see what advantage you get from the `Schedule` class, nor either why it needs to be tightly coupled to `Cinema`.  Possibly, you can break the coupling, maybe by moving members of `Cinema` into the `Schedule` class, and having `Cinema` access them by invoking appropriate methods of `Schedule`.  Alternatively, it might make more sense to just merge `Schedule` into `Cinema` instead of having it as a separate class.  If neither of those is viable, then you could consider going all the way and making `Schedule` an inner class of `Cinema`.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding. I saw no need for inheritance as I could only identify "HAS- A" type relationships, but thank you for providing a valid example of where it could be used in my application.   I am also interested in your idea of using an inner class.  The main purpose of the Schedule class is all the logic for computing start and end times for shows correctly based on cinema characteristics (And movie duration). For example it passes the Cinema size (rows and seats) to a show so that the show's seating plan is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Good sense, indeed tight coupling. Prevent it here by creating a new Interface, making Schedule more reusable probably. In the interface place all methods you want to use from Cinema. The IDE's compiler will help you there. Do not forget to add `@Overridable` in Cinema, for those interface methods.

```
public class Cinema implements Schedulable {
    private final Schedule schedule = new Schedule(this);

public class Schedule {
    public void Schedule(Schedulable schedulable) { // Instead of Cinema
```